# Is it possible to build a fiber bundle whose fibers are different? (Or we should not call it a fiber bundle?)

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles

Suppose there is a fiber bundle $E$. The base space is $M$ so that $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ is the projection. By the definition, the bundle has a typical fiber $F$ such that the local trivialization over one open subset $U_i$ of $M$ is defined in this way $\phi_i:U_i\times F\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U_i)$. So we can find out that no matter which open set $U_i$ we choose, we always choose the same typical fiber $F$. I guess this is because we want to have a smooth structure. If at different points of $M$, we choose different fibers, for example, at point $p\in M$ we attach a 3 dimensional vector space, while at point $q\in M$ we attach a 2 dimensional vector space and so on, then we are not going to have a smooth structure.

So my question is: can we attach different fibers to different points of a base manifold? If we insist to do so, is this structure still smooth? Is it still called a fiber bundle?

Comment: Sure. The base could be disconnected. (If the base is connected, then no: it's a nice exercise to show that a fiber bundle over a connected base has homeomorphic fibers, and similarly a smooth fiber bundle over a connected base has diffeomorphic fibers.)

Answer (score 6):

See the notion of *[fibration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration)*:

> A fibration is like a fiber bundle, except that the fibers need not be the same space, rather they are just homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The projection $\mathbb R^3\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb R: (x,y,z)\mapsto x$ is a smooth submersion between connected smooth manifolds and all its fibers are connected.
However the fibers are not diffeomorphic:  the fiber of $0\in \mathbb R$ is difffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ whereas all other fibers are diffeomorphic to  $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Right, but this isn't a fiber bundle.

Comment: @Qiaochu: of course it is not a locally fiber bundle, but I was answering the question "can we attach different fibers to different points of the manifold" and I wanted to give an example of a more general situation (which is also a counterexample to Ehresmann's theorem for non proper maps).